# access ag grid from ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid-angular to display data in my Angular application. There's a button which is displayed outside the ag grid. On clicking the button I need to get all rowdata from the grid. I know that an API exists for achieving this. Basically, I want to access ag grid from ts file. Please find my code below.

code in the ts file

```
this.columns = [
  {},
  {headerName: 'First Name', field: 'firstName'},
  {headerName: 'Last Name', field: 'lastName'}
];

this.rows = [
    {"", "first name1", "last name1"},
    {"", "first name2", "last name2"}
];
```

code in the html component

```
<ag-grid-angular id="myGrid" #agGrid style="width: 100%" class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rows" [columnDefs]="columns">
<ag-grid-angular>
```

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AgGrid provides different APIs to access and configure the data in the grid.

The one which you are looking for is **GridApi**, which you can get it from the Ag grid once it has been initialized though the **gridReady** event.

Hope the below code snippet answers your query.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GridApi, GridReadyEvent } from 'ag-grid-community';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <ag-grid-angular
      style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"
      class="ag-theme-balham"
      [rowData]="rows"
      [columnDefs]="columns"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
    <br />
    <button (click)="getData()">Get Data</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  columns = [
    { headerName: 'First Name', field: 'firstName' },
    { headerName: 'Last Name', field: 'lastName' }
  ];

  rows = [
    { firstName: 'first name1', lastName: 'last name1' },
    { firstName: 'first name2', lastName: 'last name2' }
  ];

  gridApi: GridApi;

  onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
    console.log(params);
    this.gridApi = params.api;
  }

  getData() {
    if (!this.gridApi) {
      return;
    }
    const rowCount = this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount();
    for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      const rowNode = this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(i);
      console.log(`row ${i + 1} -> `, rowNode.data);
      // Perform your logic
    }
  }
}
```

Refer [official documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/) of Ag-Grid Angular for more information.
Cheers and happy coding!!!

Comment: I tried the above example, but it didn't really work.